# JSON decode/encode with "&" symbol SLIM Framework empty row at db

Tags: php, json, slim-3

I have a simply API with SLIM3, through a form, when i enter the symbol "&". An empty row is filled in my database. The lack of the symbol "&" works.

Example of good JSON ->

```
Object { post_ID: 0, post_date: "2018-09-29", post_content: "Test post contest", post_image: "image-1538221739-psql-324x235.png", article_tittle: "Test article tittle", article_content: "<ol><li><strong>Test Body</strong></li><li>Test 2</li></ol>", post_category: "DEV" }
createpost.component.ts:34:2
Object { status: "success", code: "200", message: "FIle uploaded.", filename: "image-1538221748-psql-324x235.png" }
```

Example of bad JSON ->

```
Object { post_ID: 0, post_date: "2018-09-29", post_content: "Test post contest", post_image: "image-1538221748-psql-324x235.png", article_tittle: "Test article tittle&", article_content: "<ol><li><strong>Test Body</strong></li><li>&oacute; &ntilde;</li></ol>", post_category: "DEV" }
createpost.component.ts:34:2
Object { status: "success", code: "200", message: "FIle uploaded.", filename: "image-1538221829-psql-324x235.png" }
```

As you can see the first JSON fills correct in the database but the second JSON, because has the symbol "&" fill an empty row.

This is my function for create post.

```
//Create post
$app->post('/posts/', function() use($app, $db){
    $json = $app->request->post('json');
    $data =json_decode($json, true);

    if (!isset($data['post_date'])){
        $data['post_date']=null;
    }
    if (!isset($data['post_content'])){
        $data['post_content']=null;
    }
    if (!isset($data['post_category'])){
        $data['post_category']=null;
    }
    if (!isset($data['post_image'])){
        $data['post_image']=null;
    }
    if (!isset($data['article_tittle'])){
        $data['article_tittle']=null;
    }
    if (!isset($data['article_content'])){
        $data['article_content']=null;
    }   
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts ( post_ID, post_date, post_content, post_category, post_image, article_tittle, article_content) VALUES ( NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $post_date, $post_content, $post_category, $post_image, $article_tittle, $article_content);

    $post_date = $data['post_date'];
    $post_content = $data['post_content'];
    $post_category = $data['post_category'];
    $post_image = $data['post_image'];
    $article_tittle = $data['article_tittle'];
    $article_content = $data['article_content'];
    $stmt->execute();
    //$query = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES(NULL,
    //"."'{$data['post_date']}'".",
    //"."'{$data['post_content']}'".",
    //"."'{$data['post_category']}'".",
    //"."'{$data['post_image']}'".",
    //"."'{$data['article_tittle']}'".",
    //"."'{$data['article_content']}'".")";
    //$insert = $db->query($query);

    $result = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'code' => '404',
            'message' => 'Post not added.'
            );
    if($stmt){
        $result = array(
            'status' => 'success',
            'code' => '200',
            'message' => 'Post added.'
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
        $stmt->close();
});
```

I tried to decode with http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php but with an unexpected result. What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly i'm aware of that.

I must fix JWT and the security in SQL as you said, anyway thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you fix it now, you may find that this error magically disappears as a side effect of doing it right

Comment: @CitizenG1 - You should start by following RiggsFolly's advice. That will require you to change your query and escaping etc won't be an issue. That in itself might actually solve your problem. It's also a bit of a waste of time to debug code that you need to rewrite anyway.

Comment: Also writing INSERT's without the Column List can be dangerous. If someone changes the order of the columns (yes it can happen) then your queries at best will put data in the wrong column or at worst will crash because of datatype mismatches

Comment: Also if you are using MYSQLI_ Add some Error checking. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: updated the code with prepared statement, sadly the error persist, now if i add the symbol &, no row created, without the symbol &, all is fine.